# PHP Measure function memory usage

Tags: php, memory

I want to measure how much memory my function is using. As I want to do 10 iterations I'm using `for` loop for this. The problem is that after first iteration memory usage is always the same. What should I do that memory is calculated as first iteration to calculate averages?

My code snippet:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $memoryStart = memory_get_usage();
    $basketsWithFilter = $customer->getBasketsExceedTotal(total: 5);
    $memoryEnd = memory_get_usage() - $memoryStart;
    $memoryWithFilter[] = round($memoryEnd / 1024);
}
```

In the array results are the following
`17, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2`

Comment: Divide the sum of `$memoryWithFilter` by 10? Something like `$averageMemoryUsage = array_sum($memoryWithFilter) / count($memoryWithFilter);`

Comment: I don't think an average is going to be very useful, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @NigelRen I want to collect the data of memory usage for function `getBasketsExceedTotal` for each iteration and to see how many memory was used each iteation

Comment: But that's exactly what you already have. What is it you don't understand about these results? You think that the results are not correct?

Comment: How is this information going to be used, as you can see from your existing results, the information isn't always as obvious as you would expect.  Do you think that the fist iteration takes 8 times the memory of the each of the others or do you think there may be some overhead?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Exactly, I'm thinking that over iterations are wrongly calculated that results are the same.

Comment: You're executing the same code every time, what makes you expect that the results should be different every time?

Comment: "The memory usage of a function" is not a very well-defined quantity. Do you want the *maximum* memory used *during* the function? The *additional* memory needed for the application *after* the function? Remember that `$basketsWithFilter`, and the internal state of `$customer`, also take up memory; is this what you want to measure, or something you want to exclude? Is there a specific problem you're tracking down, or is this intended to be a general benchmark?

Comment: @IMSoP the problem is in not HOW I'm measuring it and what I want to measure, but WHY results after 1 iteration are the same and HOW can I prevent that? Because it's not real one for sure

Comment: Again, you assume the data you now get is wrong: WHY?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware because it's the same and it shouldn't be the same. At least on second or third iteration it should be almost the same as first one

Comment: Clearly you know something we don't. We don't know what `$customer->getBasketsExceedTotal(total: 5);` does. For me the pattern seems correct: Iteration 1 is big, because it sets up stuff, and then the subsequent iterations use that and basically all do the same.

Comment: @wollenS The number you are currently capturing will be measuring a) the change in size of `$basketsWithFilter` when you overwrite it with a new value each iteration; plus b) the change in size of `$customer` due to any state on that object, code not shown; plus c) the change in size of other global state, code not shown. (For completeness, there's also a tiny contribution from the size of `$memoryWithFilter`, as you add more values on each iteration.) So, is that what you intended to measure? And what were you expecting to see, that leads you to question the results PHP is giving you?

Answer (score 1):

Functions such as yours generally don't consume a lot of RAM on each iteration unless they are loading data to RAM for later use, or unless the code has an unintentional memory leak.  Without seeing the code of your function it's difficult to know exactly why the after-minus-before memory usage is 10KiB on the first iteration and 2KiB on subsequent iterations. But php's runtime has reference-counted [garbage collection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php). That generally means RAM usage will creep up slowly as php allocates, releases, and reuses heap RAM for various purposes.

With respect, "average" RAM usage has no meaning unless, as mentioned, your function's purpose is to load data into RAM for later use.